# Child of entity type is null while posting to Web Api

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to post Json to web api

```
  {
      "Name" :"Irfan",
      "Roles":[
        {"RoleID" : 1}
    ,
     {"RoleID" : 2}]
    }
```

In web api i have model like this

```
public class Role
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public Int32? RoleID { get; set; }
    public Int32? UserID { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

i am getting "Name" value but "Roles" is null. How can i get "Roles"?

Comment: You are not getting Roles values its just because in Role Class "ID" column is not nullable either you can make it nullable or pass the value of "ID" in json object

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code sample which works when testing :

```
[Route("test")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> test(User user)
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

The request will like :

```
POST  https://localhost:XXXX/api/values/test
Content-Type: application/json


{"Name" :"Irfan","Roles":[{"RoleID" : 1},{"RoleID" : 2}]}
```

Checking your request using Fiddler/Postman , .NET Core will help automatically mapping json to object on server side .

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem was on my side. i was not using "public" access specifier for List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

Comment: OK , i see your updates . So that you should reply your own question rather than updating the question without explanation .

Answer (score -1):

Create object of roles in constructor

```
public class User
{
     public User()
     {
         this.Roles = new List<Role>();
     }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are not getting Roles values its just because in Role Class "ID" column is not nullable either you can make it nullable or pass the value of "ID" in json object